# Avast is reporting that my Android application is a trojan

Tags: android, antivirus

One of my apps is being reported by avast as Potentially unwanted program. It is marked by avast! both as Android:Agent-GE and Android:AndrAgent-R...

Can anyone tell me some more info about this, so I can locate what exactly is considered a virus in this app.
This is a very simple app, so I have no idea what might have caused this...

Is there a possibility that the computer that built the APK was infected and that it injected some trojan in the application?

I have reported this as false positive and also contacted avast via their forum. But I guess it wont hurt to post here as well, maybe someone have/had a similar problem.

Comment: I think this is a valid question

Comment: I would love to see Avast's response to this question.

Comment: It might be some part of his code that has to do with the anti-virus flagging it off as a trojan. I think it's a valid question.

Comment: You havent just copied all permissions into your app have you?.. It could be flagged, due to excessive demand of permisisons, or requesting permissions that should ideally not be used. Just a thought.

Comment: No, the app only requests INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Comment: I have the same problem. All of my apps created by Corona sdk are now flagged by Google Play as a problem. My Android devices using Avast also flag them as suspect. There are no special permissions in these apps.

Comment: read here https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=179031.0